# deserialize xml nodes and place it in the same xml file

Tags: xml, serialization, nodes

my XML file is like this:

```
<root>
   <node1>
      <texts>
              <text>
                  <type>type1</type>
                  <pro1>IN</pro1>
                  <pro2>ES</pro2>
                  <finalText><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXX]]></finalText>
            </text>         
   </texts>
 <node1>
<root>
```

I want to duplicate the "text" node for every "pro1" and "pro2" nodes.
I tried to deserialize but no success. How can I achieve this?
The output should be like this:

```
<root>
   <node1>
      <texts>
              <text>
        <type>type1</type>
        <pro1>IN</pro1>                 
        <finalText><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXX]]></finalText>
         </text>
         <text>
        <type>type1</type>
        <pro2>ES</pro2>                 
        <finalText><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXX]]></finalText>
        </text>       
   </texts>
 <node1>
<root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for my $pro in /root/node1/texts/text/*[xsh:matches(name(), '^pro\d+$')] {
    $new := cp $pro/../self::text before $pro/.. ;
    rm $new/*[xsh:matches(name(), '^pro\d+$')][name() != name($pro)] ;
}
rm /root/node1/texts/text[last()] ;

save :b;
```